# ECLIPSE - Exception occurred executing command line

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a MAC with java 7 and when I try to execute my code eclipse generates this error:

```
Exception occurred executing command line. Cannot run program "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" (in directory "/Users/mrcf/Documents/Università/EclipseWS/Clean"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Can you help me?

Please, are two days that I try but without success.

Thanks.

Comment: can you try creating new workspace ?

Comment: So...does that directory exist?

Comment: @JigarJoshi: yes, twice!

Comment: what this directory has ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi this directory contains the src file and the bin file of the java project called "Clean"

Comment: is the directory exist ? if yes can you try renaming it to normal english character and try again ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi What do you mean "normal english character"??

Comment: `Università` to `Universita`

Comment: @JigarJoshi ok! just a minute!

Comment: @JigarJoshi damn italian accents, now it works ... thanks!

Comment: I will add it as answer for future and other's reference :)

Comment: or try adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in `eclipse.ini` with that Italian character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `Università` to `Universita` in directory name